# Replacement for spring form tag in facelets

Tags: spring, jsf, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, facelets

since I know I can't use the Spring tag library in Facelets, I wonder if anyone can tell me what should I use instead of

```
<sf:form method="POST" modelAttribute="spitter">
.....
</sf:form>
```

Where prefix `sf` refers to (in JSP only):

`<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>`

I really like the idea of this form, that it binds all properties directly to `modelAttribute` object.
Is there any possibility that `<h:form>...</h:form>` can do the same?
Or is there any other tag, that can handle it?

I can't use JSP because i want to use PrimeFaces.

I'm just a beginner in J2EE, so please be patient :)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `<h:form>` does a similar thing. Even though the JSF approach is a bit different, the end result is similar: With spring the object gets submitted, and with jsf the field values end up in your managed bean. You will just have to use

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.property}" />
```

(where `bean` is a `@ManagedBean`-annotated class (for jsf2), or declared in faces-config (for jsf1))

This difference is that the spring form is submitted to the target url, and spring finds the target method based on the mapping, while here you specify which method of the managed bean to invoke in your `<h:commandButton />`

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, I have to use `@ManagedBean` annotation? Now I'm using Spring MVC and my Controller is annotated with `@Controller` and `@RequestMapping`. Can I have my controller class annotated with both `@Controller` and `@ManagedBean`?

Comment: you can't use both spring-mvc and jsf. They have different "philosophies".

Comment: So, I have to use Spring MVC and JSP. But in JSP I can't use PrimeFaces, right?

Comment: that's right. You can use JSF+spring, but not with spring-mvc

Comment: Be sure to connect the IOC Spring functionality to the FacesContext through the SpringELResolver to be able to use Spring service and dao classes if this is your case. This is set in the faces-config.xml file. <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>